# method automatically calls when starting the program

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I'm working on a program that takes data from a spreadsheet and enters it into a contract template, then converts it into a PDF. I've created a simple GUI using tkinter, and I'd like to have a button that opens a new window, allowing users to select the .xlsx file they'd like to work from. I can't seem to figure out how to get my program to run without calling the `importSpread` method right when the program starts.

Here are the relevant portions of my code:

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '\\'

        self.importButton = Button(master, text = 'Import Spreadsheet',
                                                     command = self.importSpread,
                                                     height = 1, width = 20)

        self.importButton.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = W)

    def importSpread(self):
        my_filetypes = [('excel files', '.xlsx')]
        fileName = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent = self.master,
                                        initialdir = self.root,
                                        title = "Please select a file:",
                                        filetypes = my_filetypes)
        return fileName

window = Tk()
myGUI = GUI(window)
fileName = self.importSpread()

window.mainloop()
```

It seems as though as soon as I instantiate the `myGUI` object by saying `myGUI = GUI(window)`, the `importSpread` method is automatically called. I'd also like `importSpread` to return the `fileName` to be used later. How do I retain the value the method returns without calling the method itself? I want the program to start and remain static until the user presses the `"Import Spreadsheet"` button. I'm fairly new to python and GUIs in general, so I could be missing something basic. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Instead of posting the "relevant portions," are you able to make this a working reproducer?

Comment: This works fine for me. I would make sure that you don't call `self.importSpread` when defining the `Button` object. Just make sure you don't have `()`  after the function--just as you have it here.

Comment: what are you expecting this line  `fileName = self.importSpread()`  to do?